# XLib, XTestFakeKeyEvent latences

Tags: c++, xlib

I try to send key to an application with XLib and XTestFakeKeyEvent, and it works fine, with the following code :

```
XSetInputFocus(disp, list[selectWindow],RevertToPointerRoot,CurrentTime);
for(i=0;i<hello.size();i++){
    tamper[0] = hello[i];
    KeySym key = XStringToKeysym(tamper);
    XTestFakeKeyEvent(disp,XKeysymToKeycode(disp, key),True, CurrentTime );
    XTestFakeKeyEvent(disp,XKeysymToKeycode(disp, key),False, CurrentTime );
}
```

Where Select list[selectWindow] is the window where I send data, and tamper a char[2] (to convert char from hello[i] to char * for the function.
This code write the content of the hello wariable into the selected window, but the, I tried to send the Return key,

```
XSetInputFocus(disp, list[selectWindow],RevertToPointerRoot,CurrentTime);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(disp,XKeysymToKeycode(disp, XK_Return),True, CurrentTime );
XTestFakeKeyEvent(disp,XKeysymToKeycode(disp, XK_Return),False, CurrentTime );
```

So I select the window again, and send the XK_Return key to the application, but it don't work, I think this is because of a 'lag' with Xlib, because if I put a wait(2) at the end of the 'for' loop,it works fine, but I don't want to wait during 2seconds each time I send a message.

I don't know how I can do to solve that.

Thank you.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. I've found two workarounds. First, the waiting after sending. I've found that I can wait much less than 2 seconds. Using usleep it works with only a tenth of a second wait. Second, if I send two (or more) Returns, all but the first work correctly (with no "sleep"ing).

Comment: @MPT, you can even use `nanosleep()`

Answer (score 1):

XFlush(disp) or XSync(disp, false) after calling XTestFakeKeyEvent?

Comment: Neither of these (nor both together) solved this issue for me.

Comment: `XFlush` fixed it for me after doing `XTestFakeKeyEvent`! It was driving me nuts I totally missed that. Thanks pzan!